# macro compilation failing as Invalid use of property

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing my first ms word macro which iterates through all rows of the table and deletes the selected one. Here is the code

```
Sub TableCleaner()
'
' TableCleaner Macro
'
'
    Dim objTable As Table
    Dim sourceDocument As Document
    Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument
    Dim UserChoice As String
    Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String
    QuestionToMessageBox = "Delete row with Text?"

    Dim targetRows() As Row
    ReDim targetRows(1 To 1) As Row
    For Each oRow In sourceDocument.Tables(1).Rows
        UserChoice = MsgBox(oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbYesNo, "Delete Row?")
        If UserChoice = vbYes Then
            targetRows(UBound(targetRows)) = oRow
            ReDim Preserve targetRows(1 To UBound(targetRows) + 1) As Row
            oRow.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorLightGreen
        End If
    Next oRow

    Confirmation = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Confirm?")
    If Confirmation = vbYes Then
        For Each targetRow In targetRows
            targetRow.Delete
        Next targetRow
    End If

End Sub
```

I am following getting an error at line `targetRows(UBound(targetRows)) = oRow`

```
Compile error:
Invalid use of property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Set` the target row:

```
Set targetRows(UBound(targetRows)) = oRow
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because a `Row` is an object, not a string, number or something "simple".

When you assign an object you need to use the keyword `Set`. (Happens to me all the time in similar situations!) So:

```
Set targetRows(UBound(targetRows)) = oRow
```

Note: You should use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code modules. That forces you to declare (use `Dim`) every variable you use and will help avoid spelling errors with variable names, etc.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, on below line, it is expecting an index value like 1, 2, 3 for targetRows

targetRows(**UBound(targetRows)**) = oRow

Comment: Not working, tried hard-coded value as well `targetRows(UBound(targetRows)) = 1 'oRow.Cells(1).RowIndex`